# Recover TADOQuery in State dsInsert after disconnect

Tags: delphi, ado, adodb

We use a Delphi TADOQuery with an explicit connection for inserts.

**Summary:**
When the connection is lost while the query is in State dsInsert, the query seems to enter an inconsistent state with respect to the underlying ADO recordset. As a result, the query cannot be used anymore, even if the connection has been reestablished.

**Details:**

Assume the following simplified steps:

```
  quTest.Connection:= ADOConnection1;
  quTest.Open;
  quTest.Insert;
  //Simulate lost connection
  ADOConnection1.Close;

  try
    //quTest.State is still dsInsert
    quTest.Post; //Throws 'Operation is not allowed when the object is closed'. This is the expected beavior.
  except
    //Reconnect (simplified algorithm)
    ADOConnection1.Connected:= true;
  end;

  //quTest.State is still dsInsert
  //So far, so good.
  //Now let's close or abort or somehow reset quTest so that we can use it again. How? 
  quTest.Close //throws 'Operation is not allowed when the object is closed'
```

The problem is that at the end of the code sample above quTest is still in State dsInsert, but the underlying ADO recordset is disconnected.
Any attempt to close or somehow reset quTest fails with an exception 'Operation is not allowed when the object is closed'.

Please note that our goal is not to continue the initial insert operation. We just want to bring the query back to a state where we can open and use it again.

Is this possible?

Since quTest is part of a datamodule with design-time field bindings, we cannot easily free the broken query and create a new query instance.

Edit:
Of course, the simulation of the disconnect is not too realistic.
However, comparing the stack traces of the production error and the test sample, we see that the test is good enough.

```
Production stack trace:

================================================================================
Exception class  : EOleException
Exception message: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed
EOleException.ErrorCode : -2146824584
================================================================================
[008B9BD7] Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.InternalGotoBookmark + $17
(0000E290) [0040F290]
[008B9BD7] Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.InternalGotoBookmark + $17
[008B9BF4] Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.InternalSetToRecord + $14
[0081EEBE] Data.DB.TDataSet.InternalSetToRecord + $2
[0081D576] Data.DB.TDataSet.SetCurrentRecord + $62
[0081D9A4] Data.DB.TDataSet.UpdateCursorPos + $10
[0081E378] Data.DB.TDataSet.Cancel + $68
[0081AA49] Data.DB.TDataSet.SetActive + $AD
[0081A841] Data.DB.TDataSet.Close + $9


Test case stack trace:

Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.InternalFirst
Data.DB.TDataSet.SetCurrentRecord(0)
Data.DB.TDataSet.UpdateCursorPos
Data.DB.TDataSet.Cancel
Data.DB.TDataSet.SetActive(???)
Data.DB.TDataSet.Close
```

In fact, since the query state is still dsInsert, an attempt to .Cancel is made, resulting in subsequent calls to the ADO recordset which fail.

```
procedure TDataSet.SetActive(Value: Boolean);
begin
...
        if State in dsEditModes then Cancel;
...
end;
```

**Edit 2:**
The problem is not easy to reproduce, since it seems to be data dependent.
That's why I created a console test program.
Please run the test program twice and change the test case in the main block.
The output of the tests at my machine is shown below.

Console test program:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Data.DB,
  Data.Win.ADODB,
  ActiveX;

procedure Setup(aConnection: TADOConnection; aEmpty: Boolean);
var
  query: TADOQuery;
begin
  query:= TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    query.Connection:= aConnection;

    //Create test table
    try
      query.SQL.Add('create table test3 (a int)');
      query.ExecSQL;
      WriteLn('Table created.');
    except
      on e: Exception do
        Writeln(e.Message);
    end;

    //Clear test table
    query.SQL.Clear;
    query.SQL.Add('delete test3');
    query.ExecSQL;

    if not aEmpty then begin
      //Create a row
      query.SQL.Clear;
      query.SQL.Add('insert into test3 values (0)');
      query.ExecSQL;
    end;
  finally
    query.Free;
  end;
end;

var
  con: TADOConnection;
  query: TADOQuery;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    con:= TADOConnection.Create(nil);
    query:= TADOQuery.Create(nil);
    try
      con.ConnectionString:= 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=10.0.0.11,1433;Initial Catalog=TestDB';
      con.Connected:= true;

      //Test case 1: With data
      Setup(con, false);

      //Test case 2: No data
      //Setup(con, true);

      query.Connection:= con;
      query.SQL.Add('select * from test3');
      query.Open;
      query.Insert;
      con.Close;
      WriteLn('query.Active: ' + BoolToStr(query.Active));
      WriteLn('query.State: ' + IntToStr(Ord(query.State)));
      query.Close;
      WriteLn('Test ran without exception.');
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln('Exception: ' + E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    ReadLn;

    query.Free;
    con.Free;
  end;
end.
```

**Test-Environment:**

- Delphi 10 Seattle Version 23.0.21418.4207
- Console test program platform: Win32
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)

Tested on:

- Windows 8.1 Pro in IDE
- Windows 8.1 Pro
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, 6.1.7601 SP1 Build 7601
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Output of test case 1:

```
There is already an object named 'test3' in the database
query.Active: 0
query.State: 0
Test ran without exception.
```

Output of test case 2:

```
There is already an object named 'test3' in the database
query.Active: -1
query.State: 3
Exception: EOleException: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed
```

Comment: The problem you are getting is because of the way you are trying to simulate a disconnection.  When you call AdoConnection1.Close, this abandons the insert, and closes quTest.  So, when you call quTest.Post, this is bound to fail (its state is then dsInactive).

Comment: Open the query, thats all

Comment: @MartynA No. Right before quTest.Post, quTest.State is still dsInsert. We expect quTest.Post to fail. We want to recover quTest afterwards.

Comment: @SirRufo quTest.Open will throw 'Operation is not allowed when the object is closed', just as quTest.Close or quTest.Cancel.

Comment: I'm not arguing about this.  Put a breakpoint on quTest.Post and when it trips, evaluate quTest.State.  What is its value?  Likewise quTest.Active?

Comment: @MartynA That's what I've done, that's what you can see in the stack traces I've added above. quTest.State is dsInsert, quTest.Active is true.

Comment: Never mind stack traces.  Could you just answer my question please?

Comment: @MartynA On the breakpoint at quTest.Post, quTest.Active evaluates to true, and quTest.State evaluates to dsInsert.

Comment: @MartynA While quTest.State is not affected by ADOConnection1.Close, the state of the underlying recordset IS affected. Before ADOConnection1.Close, quUser.RecordSet.State is 1. After ADOConnection1.Close, quUser.RecordSet.State is 0.

Comment: To simulate a real disconnection you need to disconnect from the network. in that situation the ADOConnection.Connected is still true. You will need to close and open the DataSet.

Comment: @kobik Thanks for your hint. My observation in our production system was: I wanted to close the query after a reconnect, but this did not work. Analysis of the stack trace and ADO source code showed: the query was still in State dsInsert, so an implicit Cancel was triggered at Close, which failed because of an invalid internal recordset state. While the sample test code above certainly is not realistic for a real-life disconnect, it reproduces the state observed in production. Thus the question: How to recover a query in this state?

Comment: I can't reproduce what you say.

Comment: Delphi version? what OS version? have you tried the console test on other machine? Have you run this from IDE or outside the IDE? (I have seen weird things when running ADO from IDE) Anyway, I still can't repro (D7/Win7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the observed behavior is a change in or before Delphi XE6, which I think is a bug.

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15545

Summary:

- The problem does not occur in Delphi 2007 and Delphi XE.
- The problem occurs in Delphi 10.1
- The problematic code change has been introduced in or before XE6 in TDataSet.SetActive, where a new call to Cancel has been added.
- This call fails in the described scenario leading to the described effects.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like posting an answer which doesn't actually answer the question, but
in this case I think I should because I simply cannot reproduce what you've said in
your comments regarding the state of your quTest.  Perhaps the divergence
between my results and yours is due to some part of your code or object properties
that are not included in your question.

Please try this (I've tested it in D7 and Seattle):

Start a new project and drop a TAdoConnection and TAdoQuery on your form.
Make only the property changes shown in the DFM extract below;

Set up the event handlers shown in the code extract shown below.

Put breakpoints inside the `BeforeClose` and `BeforeCancel` handlers, and one on

```
quTest.Post
```

then compile, run and click Button1.

What I get is as follows:

1. The BP on BeforeClose trips.
2. The BP on BeforeCancel trip.
3. The BP on quTest.Post trips.

At step 3, the state of quTest is `dsInactive` and its `Active` property is `False`.
Those values and the fact that the `Before ...` events are called beforehand are
precisely what I would expect, given that calling `AdoConnection.Close` closes
the dataset(s) using it as their `Connection`.

So, I think that if you get different results with your app, you need to explain
why because I think I've shown that a test project does not exhibit the
behaviour you've reported.

**Update 2**

1. At the request of the OP, I added an `int` column 'a' to the table, and a corresponding `Parameter` to `quTest` and added

   quTest.Parameters.ParamByName('a').Value:= 0;

before both my calls to `quTest.Open`.  This makes **no** difference to the State and Active properties of quTest when the BP on quTest.Post trips: they are still dsInactive and False, respectively.

2. As the OP has said he just want to be able to carry on using quTest after the aborted Insert, I replaced `quTest.Post;` in the except block by `quTest.Open;`.  After that, once the Inssert exception has occurred, I can carry on using `quTest` without any apparent problem - I can do Deletes, Inserts and Edits manually and these are correctly passed back to the server, so that when the app is re-run, these changes have persisted.

**Update 3**.  The OP seems to be in some doubt that calling `AdoConnection1.Close` results in `quTest` being closed.  It **does**.  To verify this put a watch on `Form1.quTest.RecordSetState` and run the appl as far as `AdoConnection1.Close`.  Then, trace into that call.  You will find that TCustomConnection.SetConnected calls DoDisconnect
which calls ConnectionObject.Close.  That sets quTest.RecordSetState to stClosed so that when TAdoConnection.Disconnect  executes

```
for I := 0 to DataSetCount - 1 do
    with DataSets[I] do
      if stClosed in RecordsetState then Close;
```

quTest is closed.

Sample code

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    quTest: TADOQuery;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure quTestBeforeCancel(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure quTestBeforeClose(DataSet: TDataSet);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure TestReconnect;
  end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  quTest.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TestReconnect;
end;

procedure TForm1.quTestBeforeCancel(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  Caption := 'Before Cancel';
end;

procedure TForm1.quTestBeforeClose(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  Caption := 'Before close';
end;

procedure TForm1.TestReconnect;
begin
  quTest.Connection:= ADOConnection1;
  quTest.Open;
  quTest.Insert;
  //quTest.FieldByName('Name').AsString := 'yyyy'; added by MA

  //Simulate lost connection
  ADOConnection1.Close;

  try
    quTest.Post; //Throws 'Operation is not allowed when the object is closed'
  except
    //Reconnect (simplified algorithm)
    ADOConnection1.Connected:= true;
    quTest.Post;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Partial DFM

```
object ADOConnection1: TADOConnection
  Connected = True
  ConnectionString =
    'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Initia' +
    'l Catalog=MATest;Data Source=MAI7'
  Provider = 'SQLOLEDB.1'
  Left = 24
  Top = 24
end
object quTest: TADOQuery
  Connection = ADOConnection1
  CursorType = ctStatic
  BeforeClose = quTestBeforeClose
  BeforeCancel = quTestBeforeCancel
  Parameters = <>
  SQL.Strings = (
    'Select * from TestTable')
  Left = 64
  Top = 24
end
```

**Update 1**  The following code allows the completion of the pending insert
in the `except` block.  Note the **absence** of a call to `quTest.Post` in the except block.

```
procedure TForm1.TestReconnect;
const
  SaveFileName = 'C:\Temp\testdata.xml';
begin
  quTest.Connection:= ADOConnection1;
  quTest.Open;
  quTest.Insert;
  quTest.FieldByName('Name').AsString := 'yyyy';
  quTest.SaveToFile(SaveFileName, pfXML);
  //Simulate lost connection
  ADOConnection1.Close;

  try
    quTest.Post; //Throws 'Operation is not allowed when the object is closed'
  except
    //Reconnect (simplified algorithm)
    ADOConnection1.Connected:= true;
    quTest.LoadFromFile(SaveFileName);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I also can't reproduce (D5). If I close the connection before the post, I get an exception "Dataset not in edit or insert mode." when I try to call Post. then I can re-open the connection and open the dataset.

Comment: Does it throw **"Operation is not allowed when the object is closed"** when you call `quTest.Post;`?

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I cannot reproduce the problem with your test sample. My next step is to find the difference between your test project and my test project. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, does the `quTest.Post;` in the exception block actually posts to the database??? It's unclear from your answer.

Comment: @kobik:  calling `quTest.Post` gives me "DataSet not in insert or edit mode" for me in D7 with the set-up I posted in my answer.

Comment: @MartynA, I also asked about the `quTest.Post;` in the **exception** block, after you reconnect via `ADOConnection1.Connected:= true;` b/c it throws "Dataset not in edit or insert mode." again...

Comment: @kobik: "I also asked about "  Sorry, missed that.  I get the same error in the except block, because by then quTest has lost the pending insert and accompanying State.  See my update for a work-around, but I'm not sure that a local SaveToFile will suit the OP's situation.

Comment: I found the difference. Please modify the query to 'Select * from TestTable where a=:a' and then add the following line before both open calls: quTest.Parameters.ParamByName('a').Value:= 0; Can you reproduce my problem with those changes?

Comment: You can clone the recordset. anyway, loading it from file wont help you post it back to the DB. you need to save the current record not the dataset.

Comment: Regarding SaveToFile and .Post in except block. This is not my intention. I do not want to Post the query again after the reconnect. The insert is gone, that's fine for me. I will repeat the whole operation on another, more coarse-grained level). All I need to do is to "repair" the query, so that I can use it again lateron.

Comment: "Please modify ..." I have -see point 1 in update 2 in my answer - it makes no difference.  "Regarding SaveToFile and .Post in except block":  See point 2 in my Update 2.  With the change I describe, I can carry on using quTest without any problem after the Insert exception occurs (apart from the loss of the insert, obviously).

Comment: @MartynA The problem seems to depend on the actual data. Case 1: The query matches one or more rows => problem does not occur. Case 2: The query does not match a row => problem occurs. (Just empty the test table.) Can you confirm?

Comment: @nang:  Sorry, I think you are barking up the wrong tree.  See my update 3, which explains how calling AdoConnection1.Close results in quTest being closed - that's all there is to it.

Comment: @MartynA You are right. AdoConnection.Close closes the query. However, in the described problem situation, this implicit close will fail silently. (If you are able to reproduce the problem, uncheck "Ignore exception" for Exception and EOleException in Debugger settings and debug into AdoConnection.Close). For better reproducability, I created a console test program, see updated description above.